# Add a span tag inside a h5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert a span with a class using javascript inside this h5 tag which will apply to the first word:

```
<div class="container_skitter" style="width: 715px; height: 230px;">
   <div class="image">
      <a href="#">
      <div class="label_skitter" style="width: 715px; display: block;">
        <h5>Increase knife life</h5>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**After**

```
<div class="container_skitter" style="width: 715px; height: 230px;">
   <div class="image">
      <a href="#">
      <div class="label_skitter" style="width: 715px; display: block;">
        <h5><span class="firstword">Increase</span> knife life</h5>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is it something like this?

```
<script>
    $('h5').html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(\w+\s\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>')
});
</script>
```

Can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: Vanilla javascript or javascript and/or jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Add this under document.ready. Your script runs too early before DOM has been loaded completely. Also you need to match only the first word so this is enough to select it. `/(\w+\s)/`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('h5').html(function (i, html) {
     return html.replace(/(\w+\s)/, '<span class="test">$1</span>')
     });
   });
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ENeHv/)

Comment: @Simon is this what you expect?

Comment: Why do you pass 'i' to the function? Seems like you never use it?

Comment: @raam86 Read through this http://api.jquery.com/html/. It should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Let's try and do this without JQuery!

```
<script>
    Array.prototype.slice.call (document.querySelectorAll ('h5')).forEach
      function (h5el) {
        // we will come here with h5el referencing an h5 of the document
        h5el.innerHTML = h5el.innerHTML.replace (/^(\w+)\s/, 
          '<span class="firstword">$1</span> ';
      });
</script>
```

Place this script just before or just after the  tag and presto, all your `h5` elements will be modified.